# Hour-only increments in datepicker?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an issue I would hope is fixable without JS but I doubt it (could be browser specific)

I have a class with a DateTime property, and have applied the `DataFormatString` to include only the HOURS component of the time:

```
[Display(Name = "Start Date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yy HH}")]
public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
```

In viewing, this works fine:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateStart)
```

That produces "12-12-20 08" as expected, but in editing / creating I still get the minutes component of time displaying in the box and as a selector in the datepicker, whether I use the `Html` helper tag, or the `asp-for` attribute:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateStart, new { type = "date" })

<input asp-for="DateStart" class="form-control" />
```

Is this something I can control from my C# code? Can I override the browser datepicker format and get rid of the minutes on date selection? I know this works when you use DATE only, but it looks like TIME always has the minutes.

I haven't been able to test in FF or EDGE yet because of security settings on my PC but I will get round to this soon on my home PC

Comment: You can try to use a input type="date" to set dd-MM-yy,and use a input type="number " to set hh.